# How to delcare a class inside a class?

Tags: javascript, class

This is my thoughts. I have googled but found nothing. Any Help is welcomed.

```
  var class = {
        variable: {
          variable: 10
        }
 }
```

Comment: Class is a `function` in JavaScript.

Comment: var class = function(){ this.innerClass = function(){ //... } }

Answer (score 1):

[Look here for how to define classes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

[This may help you further with classes inside classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323074/object-oriented-javascript-how-to-define-a-class-within-a-class-from-a-c-shar)

Answer (score 0):

class is a reserved word.  Try using something else such as:

```
 var _class = {
        variable: {
          variable: 10
        }
 };
```

Then you can use each part of the class by calling `_class` or `_class.variable`  or `_class.variable.variable` to get the values.

Comment: Why end it with }; insted of ;?

Comment: I just added the semicolon to your code and changed `class` to `_class`.  Your creating an object, just like when assigning any other variable.  Technically I think when run semicolons get added in the background if you don't include them.  But if you try running your js on something like jsbin.com the jslint tool catches it and prompts for the semicolon.